# permutation problem: cycle representation

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $n$ be an odd number. Let $C_n$ be the set of permutations $\pi$ of $[n]$ whose cycle representation has only one cycle. Let $\pi,\sigma\in C_n$. Prove that their composition $\pi\sigma$ has an odd number of cycles.

For example, we have $(123)(132)=(1)(2)(3)$ has $3$ cycles, while $(123)(123)=(132)$ has $1$ cycle. Without loss of generality, we can suppose that $\pi=(12\cdots n)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get the solution. Let 
$\alpha $ and $\beta $ be two $n$-cycles in ${S_n}$. Since $n$ is odd, $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are even and so their composition  $\alpha \beta $ is even. Since $\alpha \beta $ is even, $\alpha \beta $ must has even number disjoint cycles that are odd permutation. Otherwise $\alpha \beta $ would be odd.  By odd(even) cycle, I mean that a cycle that is odd(even) permutation. Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be the number of odd cycles, even cycles that differ from idendity and idendities which are included in $\alpha \beta $, respectively. For example, let 
$x = \left( {12} \right)\left( {349} \right)\left( {578} \right)\left( 6 \right)$ in 
${S_9}$, then $a = 1$, $b=2$ and $c=1$. Now, what I need to show is that $a+b+c$ is odd. By above observation, $a$ must be even. What about $b$ and $c$? Note that an odd(even) cycle consists of even(odd) numbers and note that idendity consists of only one number. Now, suppose $b$ is even. Then, 
$E + E + c = n$. Since $n$ is odd, $c$ is odd and so $a+b+c$ is odd. Now, suppose $b$ is odd. Then, since  $E + O + c = n$ and $n$ is odd, $c$ is even and so $a+b+c$ is odd. Here, E is an even number and O is odd number.

Comment: I think you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not true. For example, let 
$\alpha  = \left( {123} \right)$ and $\beta  = \left( {456} \right)$ in 
${S_7}$. Then, 
$\alpha \beta  = \left( {123} \right)\left( {456} \right)$ has two cycles.

Comment: Maybe I did not state clearly. In $S_7$, the permutation $\alpha=(123)$ is in fact $(123)(4)(5)(6)(7)$. It has $5$ cycles, rather than "only one cycle". The same thing happens to the $\beta$ in your example. The resulting permutation $\alpha\beta$ has $3$ cycles: $(123)(456)(7)$.